# Nexenta/OpenSolaris server reboots endlessly after upgrading NCP 2.0rc2 to NCP 3.0a4

Tags: opensolaris, nexenta

I've got a working NexentaCore Platform 2.0rc2 (OpenSolaris b104) machine, which I'm trying to bring up-to-date using `apt-clone upgrade` --- NCP 3.0a4 (OpenSolaris b124).

The upgrade process appears to complete successfully, however the machine reboots right after I select the new checkpoint in the GRUB menu.

When I boot the new checkpoint with "-v", I see the following messages right before the screen flickers out for reboot:

```
 WARNING: failed to resolve 'scsa,probe' driver alias, defaulting to 'nulldriver'
 WARNING: failed to resolve 'scsa,nodev' driver alias, defaulting to 'nulldriver'
```

Not sure if this is related.

Any suggestions about how I can troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to add the -k option to the grub menu entry to have the OS falling back to mdb in case of panic. Something like:

```
.../unix -k -B $ZFS-BOOTFS,console=text -m verbose
```

Comment: Thanks.  I've tried this, and the machine ends up at a `[0]>` prompt, at which point I can't do anything but hardboot (keyboard does not respond).

Comment: What was the last message displayed just before the hang ?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. A screen capture further shows:

WARNING: failed to resolve 'scsa,probe' driver alias, defaulting to 'nulldriver'
 WARNING: failed to resolve 'scsa,nodev' driver alias, defaulting to 'nulldriver'

/kernel/fs/amd64/zfs: undefined symbol 'lbolt'
/kernel/fs/amd64/zfs: undefined symbol 'lbolt64'
WARNING: mod_load: cannot load module 'zfs'

panic[cpu0]/thread=fffffffffbc2e7a0: Cannot _init zfs module

I've done some poking around, and found that the upgraded /kernel/misc/amd64/scsi and /kernel/misc/scsi both differ from the original, at least in having the 'scsa,probe' and 'scsa,nodev' strings in them. I am not sure where those strings are coming from, though.
Copying those files from a known good just created a bunch of new errors.

Answer (score 0):

If you guys are running AMD processors, then it may be a situation where the new kernel (as Paul Archer has identified) is getting very nit picky with the older AMD lines. I ran into this where the older AMDs would result in anywhere from random reboots to unsuccessful/failing boots.